# Solving the constant 'a' in a cubic given a coordinate

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

Question:

Coordinate (-3,0) lies on the curve with the equation where 'a' is a constant.

Find two possible values of 'a' .

$$
y= (x+a)^3 + 10(x+a)^2 +25(x+a)
$$

My initial impression is to expand all the brackets and collect like terms however that doesn't seem practical given the number of terms that are going to be generated from this equation, especially in an exam scenario.

Whats the method to do his?

Comment: **Hint:** $$(a-3)^3 + 10(a-3)^2 + 25(a-3) = 0$$ Factor this.

Comment: HINT: let's say that $a-3=b$ get an equation for $b$ rather than $a$ and solve for $b$ then get $a$ from the found $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint: your equation $$0=(-3+a)^3+10(-3+a)^2+25(-3+a)$$ and then factorizing
$$(a-3)\left((a-3)^2+10(a-3)+25\right)=0$$ and this is equivalent to
$$0=(a+2)^2(a-3)$$
can you finish?

Comment: Don't you mean $(a+5)^2?$

Comment: It is correct as written.

Comment: take a pencil and a sheet of paper

Comment: I got $ (b+5)^2  $ where b = $a-3 $

Comment: So is the answer a=-2 or 3 ?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner May I ask how you derived the equivalent equation?

Comment: yes it is $$a=-2$$ or $a=3$, check it!

Comment: i have added a line for you!